# dlib, python: how to get square (not a rectangle) with the whole head (not only face)?

Tags: python, face-detection, dlib

dlib.get_frontal_face_detector() returns rectangles with detected faces on photo.

And I need to get a square that covers not only face but the whole head.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways for this
1, Train your own modal and use that 
2, Expand detected rectangle with some static value in % so that it covers whole head.

For example, Green is detected part and white is expanded (Photo courtesy: Google)

[image]